# C# forming nested List of child objects from parent object

Tags: c#, linq

I have got a class structure like below,

```
class Employees
{
public string Id {get;set;}
public string BossId {get;set;}
public List<Employees> Subordinates {get;set;}
}
```

Currently I have got a List with 4 records.

```
1. Id = 1, BossId = null
2. Id = 2, BossId = 1
3. Id = 3, BossId = 2
4. Id = 4, BossId = null
```

Now I need to form a List object as below by populating the Subordinates property.

```
Employees 
{
Id: 1
Subordinates : 
 { 
   Employees :
   {
     Id : 2
     Subordinates :
     {
       Employees:
       {
         Id: 3
         Subordinates : null
       }
     }
   }
 }
},
Id: 2
Subordinates: null
}
```

Please help

Comment: And where is your problem? Any affords so far?

Answer (score 2):

To make finding `Employees` by their `Id` easier, I suggest at first to create a dictionary:

```
var employeesById = employees.ToDictionary(emp => emp.Id, emp => emp);
```

Then you can iterate through your list and fill the `Subordinates` lists appropriatly:

```
foreach(var employee in employees)
{
    if (employee.BossId == null) continue;

    // get boss by BossId
    Employees boss = employeesById[employee.BossId];

    // make sure Subordinates is initialised
    if (boss.Subordinates == null) boss.Subordinates = new List<Employees>();

    // add subordinate
    boss.Subordinates.Add(employee);
}
```

Comment: We also need to cover the scenario when a subordinate has a boss, who is again a subordinate of another employee. We need to have the employees structured based upon hierarchy and remove employee from employees once they are added as subordinate.

Comment: @user1928158 The code does already cover multiple levels. After execution each employee has all its subordinates. So if you choose the one with no boss, you can track down, iterate his subordinates and they will also have their subordinates. This scenario is fully covered. The resulting objects _are_ an hierarichal tree. What you do with your source list is up to you. Removing employees from that list should be an easy exercise.